# python: os.path.join and '/' concatenation skipping inputs

Tags: python, path, os.path

I'm using os.path.join, as well as using / to concatenate paths in Python. For example:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('C:/Users/userName/Desktop/testfolder')
newDir = p / folderInTestFolder
# or alternatively
newDir = os.path.join(p, 'folderInTestFolder')
```

But now when concatenating three inputs (the first being a path), the code seems to be skipping my middle path.

For example,

```
p = Path('C:/Users/userName/Desktop/testfolder')
for fileName in file_list:
    newDir = p / 'csvFileFolder' / fileName
    print(newDir)
```

I'd expect the output to be:

```
C:/Users/userName/Desktop/testfolder/csvFileFolder/fileName
```

but the output ends up being

```
C:/Users/userName/Desktop/testfolder/fileName
```

Note that I had made the folder 'csvFileFolder' previously with os.makedirs(), so the directory newDir is referring to definitely exists.

I'm wondering what's going on.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: I just tried your code and it works. I didn't use the loop though.

Comment: what do you have in `file_list` ? If you have `../file_name` then this `../` can skip `csvFileFolder`

Comment: your code works correctly for me on Linux - and it doesn't matter that I don't have `'C:/Users/userName/Desktop/testfolder'` - `Path()` doesn't check if folder exists